# Div Inner Content width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div structure as follows:

```
<div id="showHide">
    <div>Alarm</div>
    <div>Alarmasdf</div>
    <div>Alarmasdffasdff</div>
```

Is there any way that I can get the width of the content like (Alarmasdffasdff). This content is the largest.

I am able to get the length of the content, but not the width. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, you should post it even if it's wrong.

Comment: What you like to do after getting the width of div holding largest content?

Comment: I need div with max width 240px , it should be center aligned(text left aligned), it should take width according to text which means:

1). if text is less, then div width will be in accordance to text.

2). But if text is large , then div must expand upto 240px and put the text in ellipses

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `div` elements have been changed to `display: inline`, the width of the element will match the content.

If this is not the case I would suggest wrapping the content in a `span`, or any other suitable inline element, and getting the width of that. For example:

```
<div id="showHide">
    <div>
        <span>Alarm</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Alarmasdf</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Alarmasdffasdff</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#showhide').find('div:last span').width();
```

Comment: Data will be dynamic. So what should i do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The Width of all of your 'div's is 100% regardless of their content. This is how block level elements behave...

Answer (score 0):

use **[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

`$( "#showhide div:contains('Alarmasdffasdff')").width(`);

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, width of a block level element is 100% regardless of its content's width. So first you need to change the display of the div to `inline-block`

```
<style>
#showHide div
{
 display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<div id="showHide">
    <div>Alarm
    </div>
    <div>Alarmasdf
    </div>
    <div>Alarmasdffasdff
    </div>
</div>

$('#showhide>div:contains("Alarmasdffasdff")').innerWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<div id="showHide">
    <div>Alarm</div>
    <div>Alarmasdf</div>
    <div>Alarmasdffasdff</div>
</div>
```

script :

```
var lastDiv = $('#showHide').find('div').last();
var lastDivWidth = lastDiv.width();

alert(lastDivWidth);
```

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/WonSeokHan/9nH7b/8/)

Comment: Data will be dynamic in nature. this is just an example. So what should i do to get the max width from the whole div content

Comment: If you have dynamic data, lastDiv.append('<div>' + dynamically Data (ex: JSON) + '</ div>')

To use.

Comment: div's text to be entered in the dynamic data.The. Widht () can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery makes it very easy.

```
$('#showHide').find('div:last').css('width');
```

`css()` returns the computed style of the element, which is the inline styling as well as default styling and any other css selector.

Without jquery it goes a little less "clean"

```
var mystyle = window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(myobject, null) : myobject.currentStyle;
```

`mystyle.width` shows the calculated width, where `myobject` is the element you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="showHide">
    <div class="content" style="width:50px" >Alarm</div>
    <div  class="content" style="width:60px">Alarmasdf</div>
    <div  class="content" style="width:120px">Alarmasdffasdff</div>
</div>
```

Custom width is given so that u can understand the difference, else every div will be having same width, and class content is added for convinience of processing

```
findWidth("Alarmasdf"); // Calls the function below


function findWidth(value)
{
var width=0;
$(".content").each(function(e){
if($(this).text()==value)
{
  width = $(this).width();
}
});
alert(width);
}
```

Check the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/46LH9/